# How can I use a DAO inside a Controller in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, dao, spring-boot

In a Spring MVC project I've a DAO class `myproj.models.UserDAO`:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserDAO {

  // UserDAO methods ...

}
```

and I should use it inside a controller, say `myproj.controllers.UserController`:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

  // UserController methods ...

  @RequestMapping(value="/{user}")
  public String create(String user) {

    // Here I want to use the UserDAO
    // ...

  }

}
```

How can I create an instance of the UserDAO object and use it inside a controller method?

Comment: Just @Autowire UserDAO

Comment: Can you please show your Spring configuration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try following

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserDAO {

  // UserDAO methods ...

}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

@Autowired //this will give you the reference to UserDAO      
UserDAO userDao; 
  // UserController methods ...

  @RequestMapping(value="/{user}")
  public String create(String user) {

    // Here I want to use the UserDAO
    userDao.userDaoMethod();
    // ...

  }

}
```

For more information on @Autowired explore [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_autowired_annotation.htm)

Comment: I tried with your code, I get this error: `Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private myproj.models.UserDAO myproj.controllers.UserController.userDao;`

Comment: `nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [myproj.models.UserDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

Comment: Make sure you are autowiring UserDAO?

Comment: Yes, inside the controller I've only that autowire.

Comment: Did you do exactly the same as mentioned in the code, every bit?

Comment: The only difference with your code is that the `UserDAO` implements the Spring `UserDetailsService` interface. Check the updated question.

Comment: I think you have multiple classes implmenting `UserDetailsService` interface. Well in such case use @Qualifier("userDAO") along with @Autowired in your controller.

Comment: The class `UserDetailsService` come from Spring Security and `UserDAO` is the only class that implements it in my project. However thanks for your help, I found the solution implementing a `UserService` class.

Comment: Then there should not be any problems. Anyway try with qualifier once if it helps.

Comment: The solution I used is this http://stackoverflow.com/a/25444074/3763649. Can be fine?

Comment: Yes you can go ahead with it.

Answer (score 0):

User `Autowired` annotation to inject a bean instance of your DAO:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

  @Autowired
  UserDAO userDao;

  @RequestMapping(value="/{user}")
  public String create(String user) {

    userDao.method();

  }

}
```